# stop reading a text file at a certain line java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

In this block of my program I am trying to get user input and compare it to each line in the file "PriceList3.txt" For each line, I am storing in some String variable. When one of those lines has some content that are the same as the user input (the contains method) I use the Pattern and Matcher classes to extract certain information and assign one part of the line of the txt file to a variable. I am seeking to stop reading the "PriceList3.txt" file after I call the setPrice method. Do you know how to stop reading the file once all the statements in the if(m.find()) are executed? I have no idea where to start.

Thank you for your response and help.

```
String regularExpr = "([\\w]+)\\s+([\\w]+)\\s+([\\d.\\d)]+)[\\D]+([\\d.\\d]+)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regularExpr);
File inFile = new File("PriceList3.txt");
Scanner read = new Scanner(inFile);
System.out.print("Enter the name and weight of the item: ");
String item = scan.nextLine();
while(read.hasNextLine())
{
    String each = read.nextLine();
    if(each.contains(item))
    {
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(each);
        if(m.find())
        {
            String itemName1 = m.group(1).trim()+ " " + m.group(2);
            itemName.setName(itemName1);
            String weight = (m.group(3).trim());
            double weight1 = Double.parseDouble(weight);
            itemName.setWeight(weight1);
            double itemPrice = Double.parseDouble(m.group(4).trim());
            itemName.setPrice(itemPrice);
        }
        cashier1.addItem(itemName);
    }
}
```

Comment: `break` will stop and exit the loop. So if you put that at the end of your if statement you will break through the will loop and run the code after it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stop the while loop, the easiest was would be to add a break;

```
String regularExpr = "([\\w]+)\\s+([\\w]+)\\s+([\\d.\\d)]+)[\\D]+([\\d.\\d]+)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regularExpr);
File inFile = new File("PriceList3.txt");
Scanner read = new Scanner(inFile);
System.out.print("Enter the name and weight of the item: ");
String item = scan.nextLine();
while(read.hasNextLine())
{
    String each = read.nextLine();
    if(each.contains(item))
    {
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(each);
        if(m.find())
        {
            String itemName1 = m.group(1).trim()+ " " + m.group(2);
            itemName.setName(itemName1);
            String weight = (m.group(3).trim());
            double weight1 = Double.parseDouble(weight);
            itemName.setWeight(weight1);
            double itemPrice = Double.parseDouble(m.group(4).trim());
            itemName.setPrice(itemPrice);
            //Jumps out of the innerst loop
            break;
        }
        cashier1.addItem(itemName);
    }
}
//if break is called, the code will continue at this line
```

though some people may argue that breaking loops isn't nice (because you jump around in the code, and it can become confusing in large projects). An alternative way would be to add a boolean value

```
String regularExpr = "([\\w]+)\\s+([\\w]+)\\s+([\\d.\\d)]+)[\\D]+([\\d.\\d]+)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regularExpr);
File inFile = new File("PriceList3.txt");
Scanner read = new Scanner(inFile);
System.out.print("Enter the name and weight of the item: ");
String item = scan.nextLine();
//add the boolean
boolean complete = false;
//stops the loop once complete is false
while(read.hasNextLine() && !complete)
{
    String each = read.nextLine();
    if(each.contains(item))
    {
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(each);
        if(m.find())
        {
            String itemName1 = m.group(1).trim()+ " " + m.group(2);
            itemName.setName(itemName1);
            String weight = (m.group(3).trim());
            double weight1 = Double.parseDouble(weight);
            itemName.setWeight(weight1);
            double itemPrice = Double.parseDouble(m.group(4).trim());
            itemName.setPrice(itemPrice);
            //Sets the boolean
            complete = true;
        }
        //only adds the item if complete is false
        if( !complete ){
            cashier1.addItem(itemName);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use break statement as @Neil wrote, or you can check some variable in while check:

```
boolean stop = false;
while(read.hasNextLine() && !stop) {
...
//if you want to stop
stop = true;

}
```

Comment: I really appreciate advice from both of you. It has been really useful to me and I no longer have the issue of stopping the scanner object to read the file. However, something else strange occurs in this block. When I put in the items in order (items in the top of the file to items in bottom of file), the prices add up. When not in order, only the price of the first item is displayed. Do you have any advice on this?